# Python fnmatch negative match does not behave as expected

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

trying to match the strings that does not containt "foo" or "bar".

After many reserch I came up with something that works with in linux `kiki` (which is ironically written in python) but does not work when I use it in python:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fnmatch, re
>>> regex = fnmatch.translate("\Abla.bla.bla-((?!foo|bar).)*\Z")
>>> reobj = re.compile(regex)
>>> reobj.match('bla.bla.bla-9.9.9-123.tar.gz')
>>> reobj.match('bla.bla.bla-9.9.9-123.foo.tar.gz')
>>> reobj.match('bla.bla.bla-9.9.9-123.bar.tar.gz')
```

I would have expected the first occurence of reobj.match to return a positive match.

Please help me find where I messed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you specify here:

```
    regex = fnmatch.translate("\Abla.bla.bla-((?!foo|bar).)*\Z"
```

is a *regular expression* pattern, not a shell-style [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) pattern.  fnmatch, of course, only understands the latter.

Shell-style matching is rather limited.  To do what you want, I'd perhaps just use a regular expression, or strip the `"bla.bla.bla-"` prefix off of the filename and then check that `"foo" not in stripped_filename` and `"bar" not in stripped_filename`.

Comment: In your opinion, is there a way I could acheive what I wish to with fnmatch? the options look rather limited with fnmatch...